# How prove can't have$ |x|<|y-z|, |y|<|z-x|, |z|<|x-y|$

Tags: inequality

**Question:**

let $x,y,z\in R$,show that follow Can't be set up at the same time.
$$\begin{cases}
|x|<|y-z|\\
|y|<|z-x|\\
|z|<|x-y|
\end{cases}$$

My try: if this all is set  up,then we have
$$x^2<(y-z)^2,y^2<(z-x)^2,z^2<(x-y)^2$$
so
$$x^2+y^2+z^2<2(x^2+y^2+z^2)-2(xy+yz+xz)$$
so
$$x^2+y^2+z^2>2(xy+yz+xz)$$
I can't have contradiction,so maybe have other mehods.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we have $x \leqslant y \leqslant z$.

Then $\lvert x\rvert < \lvert z-y\rvert$ implies $y-x < z$. But $\lvert z\rvert < \lvert y-x\rvert$ implies $z < y-x$. Contradiction.

Comment: For $|x|<z-y$ to imply $y-x<z$ you seem to need $x\le0$. Where do you get that from?

Comment: We have $\lvert x\rvert = \max \{x,\, -x\}$. So $-x \leqslant \lvert x\rvert < z-y$.

Answer (score 3):

If $x,y,z$ are a solution then $-x,-y,-z$ will also be a solution, so we can assume without loss of generality that at most one of $x,y,z$ is negative.

We can also assume without loss of generality that $x\ge y\ge z$. Then $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative, and the original inequalities simplify to
$$ x < y-z  \qquad\qquad y < x-z    \qquad\qquad  |z| < x -y $$

It is now easy to derive a contradiction from the three simplified equations (actually two of them will suffice).